# Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

They are newbie to docker.
Get phpmyadmin, php, home assistant working. But I can't configure the docker well to be able to connect from php to a database. Could you help me see what the problem is.

I tried everything. I read many posts with the same error but could not get it to work.

Thank you very much

This is my modified docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php73
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql8
      MYSQL_USER: pf
      MYSQL_PASSWWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DB: ha
    ports:
      - 3001:80
  db:
    container_name: mysql8
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_USER: pf
      MYSQL_PASSWWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ha
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 6033:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: pf
      MYSQL_PASSWWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - /sessions
```

The new php example

```
<?php
  $host = 'db';
  $user = 'pf';
  $password = '123456';
  $db = 'ha';

  $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db,3306);
  if($conn->connect_error) {
    echo 'connection failed' . $conn->connect_error; 
  } 
  echo 'Sucessfully connected msql';
?>
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.3-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
EXPOSE 80
```

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php73
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    container_name: mysql8
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mediciones
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWWORD: root
    ports:
      - 6033:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: root

  homeassistant:
    container_name: homeassistant
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
      - /dev/ttyUSB1:/dev/ttyUSB1
      - /dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/homeassistant:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
      - /dev/serial/by-id/:/dev/serial/by-id/
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
```

My php example

```
<?php
  $host = '127.0.0.1';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = 'root';
  $db = 'ha';

  $conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);
  if($conn->connect_error) {
    echo 'connection failed' . $conn->connect_error; 
  } 
  echo 'Sucessfully connected msql';
?>
```

Comment: `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT`. Spelling matters.

Comment: sorry. I did not understand

Comment: I had not seen it thanks

Comment: likewise with `MYSQL_PASSWWORD`

Comment: I corrected it but the same error remains

Comment: I ask you a stupid question.
Trying to execute mysql from the command line I see that it does not exist. Shouldn't it have been installed when running docker-compose?
Could it be the problem?

Comment: No. docker compose installs things in containers only. After bringing the containers up with docker compose you can `docker exec -ti {container name} bash` and try connecting from that image. You can apt-install packages like the mysql client there to test things. The network connection environment from within a container "group/swarm?" (i forget the right term) looks rather different to the external view.

Comment: Because I refer to /var/lib/mysql and that folder does not exist

Comment: The solution was to use links: db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its your example code running in the php container:

In which case use `db` as the hostname and `mediciones` as the database name in the connection.

For the db container:

- `MYSQL_USER` set to non-root as this will cause potential errors.  This user is already given access on the `MYSQL_DATABASE`.
- use a persistent volume for /var/lib/mysql
- (optionally), if your home assistant or php doesn't create the tables, you can use [mysql "Initializing a fresh instance"]https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) to initialize some tables.

Comment: I am a bit confused as this is my first time using docker.
I just changed MYSQL_USER but it keeps logging in with root. thanks

Comment: Environment variables like `MYSQL_USER` are used by the mysql:8.0 container to affect the initialization of the database. If you are setting this for your container, you must ensure that is used in your application.

Comment: I think that I'm doing fine

Comment: The solution was to use links: db

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing `mysql` on host port: `6033`

Did you try:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db,6033);
```